# Бот отвечает в лс, а на сервере нет

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    a = message.content.replace('', '')
    b = 1 + int(a)
    await message.channel.send(b)



client.run('')
```

[image: Написал простейшего бота, он отвечает только в лс, а на сервере выдает такую ошибку]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, у бота отсутствует нужные intents - проще, у него нет права читать сообщения на вашем сервере. Если это не так, посмотрите в сторону discord api, там включите все галочки в разделе intents